# Enabling fixed position for topbar on GIS Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I'm not sure if anyone outside of the main office of Stack Exchange can really answer or provide feedback to this inquiry, but has anyone ever noticed that the topbar (where the StackExchange drop down, notifications, your profile, etc. are listed), scrolls with the body of the page?

Topbar:

[image: topbar]

So if you ever scroll down, this part of the page leaves the screen.  What if the topbar could always be visible? Something like:

```
.topbar {
     position: fixed;
     z-index 9999;
}

.container {
     padding-top: 34px;
}
```

That way no matter how far you scroll down to view questions or page content, you can still see if notifications come in or what not.

[image: adjusted]

Some of you are probably thinking, "*What's this guy's deal?*"

Honestly, I just like the idea of being able to see notifications and score changes no matter where I am on the container.

99.9% of this is just me being picky, but I wonder if anyone else see's this as a benefit?  Thoughts?

Comment: I like it, but you'll probably have better luck on Meta.SE with this. Or maybe not... it's [been asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen-optional) and doesn't appear to be popular. Not sure if our site can be different in that respect or not.

Comment: Yeah, it was a tossup if it was even possible for moderators or admins of GIS.SE to have the rights to do so.  I just noticed that the style of pages does change from site to site on SE, so maybe someone within GIS.SE had the privileges to make such changes (if in fact the change was a desired one).

Comment: I do note there are several answers at the linked Meta question that describe custom scripts that can be loaded into your browser to get this functionality. But I do still think it would be nice to have as an embedded interface option.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, we as moderators have access to relatively few site configuration options and none in the vicinity of what you are seeking.

Consequently, we would need involvement of the SE developers to implement anything like this.

I would want to know of another SE site that works the way you describe before I could become interested in trying to get it implemented here.

Consequently, I agree with @ChrisW that you will be best to pursue this via Meta SE ([Should the top navigation be frozen (optional)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen-optional)).